# Select a max date in a data set and add it as field in SQL

Tags: sql

Can I ask how to get the sql query for what I want to get? I am trying to get the max date in the entire data set but not sure how to get it. Was trying to use the partition column but it would just give me the max based on the field I choose to partition. So here's a sample:

Sample Table:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1/1/2022 |
| 2 | DEF | 1/1/2022 |
| 3 | GHI | 1/1/2022 |
| 4 | JKL | 1/1/2022 |
| 5 | MNO | 1/1/2022 |
| 6 | PQE | 1/1/2022 |

Output:

| ID | Name | Date | MAX DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1/1/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 2 | DEF | 1/2/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 3 | GHI | 1/3/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 4 | JKL | 1/4/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 5 | MNO | 1/5/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 6 | PQE | 1/6/2022 | 1/6/2022 |

Sample Table:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1/1/2022 |
| 2 | DEF | 1/1/2022 |
| 3 | GHI | 1/1/2022 |
| 4 | JKL | 1/1/2022 |
| 5 | MNO | 1/1/2022 |
| 6 | PQE | 1/1/2022 |

Output:

| ID | Name | Date | MAX DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | 1/1/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 2 | DEF | 1/2/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 3 | GHI | 1/3/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 4 | JKL | 1/4/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 5 | MNO | 1/5/2022 | 1/6/2022 |
| 6 | PQE | 1/6/2022 | 1/6/2022 |

Comment: What version of SQL? MySQL? MS SQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Something else. Also , please read the tag info for sql: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info . This will have been highlighted to you when selecting it, but you don't seem to have taken any notice. You also seem to have ignored the [tour] and [ask] guides which the system will have prompted to you read before posting anything (I can see from your empty profile you didn't get the badge). Please take the help on offer, it will assist you to make a more useful and answerable question.

Comment: Anyway, where is the max date coming from? In your "sample data" you only have 1/1/2022, but in the output you've magically got each row with a different date. So is the first task to increment the dates in the rows to a suitable level? What is the rule by which that should be done? Each date should be one day higher than the row which precedes it, when the data is ordered by ID...is that correct? have you attempted to do that? And as for your attempt to use partition...how can we help you with that if you don't show the exact code, or any output/errors that you received?